# What will be the current flowing through the Zener diode in following circuit?

Tags: mosfet, diodes, power-electronics, zener

[image]

When Vbat = 18 V, the Zener diode will be operational.  Below are two possible scenarios of gate control of the MOSFET.

- When V2 = 5 V, the MOSFET is OFF and the Zener diode is not biased.
- When V2 = Gnd (0V), the current through the Zener diode would be (Vz/R2) i.e. 15/1k = 15 mA. Is this calculation right? I tried to simulate the circuit but I'm seeing around 2 mA flowing through the Zener diode and resistor R.

Questions:

1. How do you explain the operation going on here in the two scenarios?
2. This is part of high side driver.  Can the selected 15 V Zener diode help in protecting the gate of MOSFET when the supply is greater than 16 V?

Comment: Get back to simple LED circuit as an example, it has same logic. Current through LED is defined by Vdrop of RESISTOR divided by resistance of RESISTOR. You're dividing voltage drop on zener by resistance of another component (resistor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When V2 = Gnd(0V), the current through the Zener diode would be
> (Vz/R2) i.e 15/1K = 15mA. Is this calculation right?

No, that calculation is not correct.
With just a Zener and resistor in series the current through the Zener would be the same as through the resistor, the voltage across the resistor would be the supply voltage minus the Zener voltage so you would have (Vs - Vz) / R. This neglects the other components though, you've got the 10K resistor and the MOSFET so you have to take them into account as well.

Using an ideal 15 V Zener and MOSFET with infinite gate impedance to make the math easier we'd have this:

The current through R3 would be Vz / R3 = 15 V / 10K = 1.5 mA.
The current through R2 would be (Vs - Vz) / R2 = (18 V - 15 V) / 1K = 3.0 mA.
The Zener current would be I(R2) - I(R3) = 3.0 mA - 1.5 mA = 1.5 mA.

Answer (score 1):

As an approximation, the voltage across R2 determines the current.

This voltage is either ~0V in the first scenario or ~3 V in the second scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> *When V2 = 5V, the MOSFET is OFF and the Zener diode is not biased.*

This is almost certainly incorrect....

When V2 is 5 volts, \$V_{GS}\$ is about 11.8 volts and that means that the MOSFET (almost certainly for 99.999% of MOSFETs) is well and truly on. In your circuit with the stated V2 values, the MOSFET will never turn off (not even close).

You will need an extra transistor in your circuit to make this work properly.

Think again about this because, as it stands, your circuit WILL NOT work as you expect and therefore, asking about the zener diode current is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes i have transistor based circuitry to control gate , basically from CPU-->Transistor logic--->MOSFET Gate control. For simulation purpose i have used voltage source